# A question on time complexity

Tags: normal-distribution, time-complexity

Suppose I have a sequence of i.i.d. Bernoulli random variable $X_i$ with mean $0$ and variance $1$. For each $X_i$, it is $1$ w.p $1/2$ and $-1$ w.p $1/2$.

My goal is to show $X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n \rightarrow O(\sqrt{n})$, how would I do that then?

My try is by C.L.T., I have the following

$\frac{X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n}{\sqrt{n}}\xrightarrow{C.L.T.} N(0,1)$
But I do not know how to proceed next. Can someone give some idea?

Comment: Of course, no. The mean of a sum is a sum of the means, in this case zero. The question that CLT addresses is about the variance, not mean. Means were always known

Comment: @ whuber I know the OP wrote that $P(0)=P(1)=1/2$, but we wind up with a mean of $0$ and variance of $1$ if we take $P(1)=P(-1)=1/2$, which is similar in spirit to a Bernoulli distribution. I wonder if that’s what’s going on.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I fixed it.

Comment: That leaves us still wondering what you mean by "$ \rightarrow O(\sqrt{n}).$"  Could you explain?

Comment: The material says that way. Let me share the link here:  https://faculty.fuqua.duke.edu/~jx77/stats-graphs.pdf    It's in chapter7.1

Comment: I don't see this problem in 7.1

Comment: @Ryan Volpi In 7.1 correlated recovery it mentioned. The only difference is that the I used $X_i$ here instead of $\sigma \hat{\sigma}$ because it would take me much more to explain this $\sigma$ and its background. Using $X_i$ does not affect how to get the $O(n)$ thing.